# Trying to update a particular value in a sql database via c# console

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update a particular value in a sql database.
I have been searching both stack and msdn as well as using an example I received from another user, however I still cant seem to work it out and my hands are up in the air.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Which time would you like to edit for group {0}?",newGroup);
        string ClassTime = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the current teacher and classroom for {0}",newGroup);
        string teacherandclassroom = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enter the new teacher and classroom number for group {0} at {1} ",newGroup,ClassTime));
        string newTeacherClassRoom = Console.ReadLine();
        SQLCONN.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd1 =
           new SqlCommand("UPDATE mondayTable SET " + ClassTime +" =@"+ClassTime + " WHERE " + ClassTime + "@=" + teacherandclassroom, SQLCONN)) //or WHERE newGroup?
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + ClassTime, newTeacherClassRoom);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + teacherandclassroom, teacherandclassroom);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Database Updated...");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm not getting any errors and because of this, it is hard for me to debug.
Here are the values I'm entering if it makes any difference.

[FROM TOP TO DOWN]

`09:00-09.40`

`ANDREWW`

`ANDREW 7`


The table that is being used.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mondayTable] (
[SAT]         VARCHAR(50)           NOT NULL,
[09:00-09.40] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[10:10-10:50] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[11.00-11:40] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[11:50-12:30] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[12:40-13:20] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[13:30-14:10] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[14:20-15:00] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[15:10-15:50] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[16:00-16:40] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[16:50-17:30] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[17:40-18:20] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[18:30-19:10] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[19:20-20:00] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SAT] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Those have to be some of the strangest column names I've ever seen....

Comment: agreed, there are to do with times of each period.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what the actual SQL being sent is?

Comment: indeed I have, It looked to be ok and didnt give any errors

Comment: From a readability/maintainability standpoint, wouldn't it be easier to use an identifier for each period (i.e., Period1, Period2, etc)?

Comment: I have the groups name for the identifier

Comment: In your table, in some places you've put `.` instead of `:`

Comment: yeah that was a typo I noticed as i posted the question, i fixed it up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using brackets, and the @ was in the wrong side of the =

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE mondayTable SET [" + ClassTime +"] = @newValue WHERE [" + ClassTime + "] = @oldValue", SQLCONN)) //or WHERE newGroup?
{
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", newTeacherClassRoom);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldValue", teacherandclassroom);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Database Updated...");
}
```

But your code allow SQL Injection... Take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a shot, question, using parameters, I was always told that stop help stop injections? is that true?

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution you have written didn't work or give any errors, thanks for pointing out that the @ symbol was on the wrong side and thanks for contributing.

Comment: wow wee, It worked!, I know what you have helped me with is more than enough, however so I dont have to ask in the future and not just a control C control V junkie, could you explain why this works over my questions code?

Comment: I think the parameter names (starting with @) doesn't allow caracters like : and -

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117844/discussion-between-lmcarreiro-and-werdna).